# Typescript useQuery Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

What would be the type which I have defined as any? I have tried TQueryFnData as per the RQ docs. but get `Cannot find name 'TQueryFnData'`

```
export const useFetchUser = (userID: string | undefined) => {
    return useQuery<any, Error>([users.fetchUser, userID],
        () => axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
            .then(response => response.data))
}
```

An example of the data returned is: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`

```
export interface Users {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    address: Address,
    phone: string,
    website: string,
    company: Company
}

export interface Address {
  ...
}

export interface Geo {
  ...
}

export interface Company {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described [in the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/typescript#type-inference) and [in my blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script), the best thing you can do is make sure that your query function is typed to return a Promise of the type you'd expect. Then, you don't need to pass generics to useQuery at all.

There are many ways to achieve that:

1. declare return type on the queryFn:

```
export const useFetchUser = (userID: string | undefined) => {
    return useQuery([users.fetchUser, userID],
        (): Promise<User> => axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
            .then(response => response.data))
}
```

2. declare a generic for axios.get:

```
export const useFetchUser = (userID: string | undefined) => {
    return useQuery([users.fetchUser, userID],
        () => axios.get<User>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
            .then(response => response.data))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix typo -

```
export interface Users
// to
export interface User
```

It is useQuery<Users, Error>

```
export const useFetchUser = (userID: string | undefined) => {
    return useQuery<User, Error>([users.fetchUser, userID],
        () => axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
            .then(response => response.data))
}
```

Lastly here's a working example of your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-spence-lr9dc5?file=/src/SessionManager.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

As the docs suggest, typing the fetcher function is the best way.

But for use-cases where you use a common fetcher function, Type Generics would be the go to way.

```
type ApiResponse<T> = {
  data: T;
  // You might want to include other properties like status, message, etc.
};

export const fetcher = async <T>({ queryKey: [url] }: QueryFunctionContext) => {
  if (typeof url === 'string') {
    return axiosInstance.get<ApiResponse<T>>(url).then((res) => res.data.data);
  }

  throw new Error('Invalid url provided');
};
```